# Format time labels in charts_flutter time series chart to include hh:mm:ss

Tags: charts, dart, flutter

Is it possible to format the labels on the xAxis of a charts_flutter time series chart to display *hh:mm:ss*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51138909/1954993) explains how to go about formatting the code to display months and days but the information I need to display is collected a few times a minute.

`charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec` doesn't allow for specifying seconds. The OP on the above question alluded to a `DateTimeFactory` which is mentioned in the charts_flutter gallery, but I'm also unsure how to use this, or if it is even of any use in this situation.

```
new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
  getSeries(item),
  animate: false,
  primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
    tickProviderSpec: new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false)
  ),
  domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
    tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
      hour: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(format: 'hh', transitionFormat: 'dd/MM hh:mm'),
    )
  ),
),
```

Alternatively, is there a different chart I could use that would allow for this functionality? I see that `charts.BarChart` allows for Strings on the xAxis, but I specifically need a line chart - is there some way of specifying strings rather than datetimes on a line chart if the above formatting is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of a setting down in `MinuteTimeStepper`, there's no point. The smallest interval that you can achieve between labels appears to be 5 minutes. The `MinuteTimeStepper` defaults to intervals of 5, 10, 15, 20 and 30 minutes.

```
class MinuteTimeStepper extends BaseTimeStepper {
  static const _defaultIncrements = const [5, 10, 15, 20, 30];
```

It has a constructor that allows you to pass in your own list, but I can't figure out how to get that to work.

Instead, I just modified it to become `const [1, 5, 10...` and that now draws labels with a 1 minute gap (if space is available).

Given that the closest the labels will be drawn (even with this change) is every minute, there's no point in including seconds.

Taking [the sample](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/simple) and modifying the series data to

```
  new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2018, 8, 22, 13, 00, 00), 15),
  new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2018, 8, 22, 13, 00, 30), 5),
  new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2018, 8, 22, 13, 01, 00), 25),
  new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2018, 8, 22, 13, 01, 30), 20),
  new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2018, 8, 22, 13, 02, 00), 10),
```

gives labels that read `1 00`, `01` and `02` (1PM exactly, 1 minute past and 2 minutes past) which are generated by the default format of `mm` and `h mm`. Note that the points at the half minute are drawn, but not labeled, as expected.

If you wanted these in 24 hour format you could add a `TimeFormatterSpec` like

```
        minute: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
          format: 'mm', // or even HH:mm here too
          transitionFormat: 'HH:mm',
        ),
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much - could I just ask how you're able to specify your own `MinuteTimeStepper` - I can't see where that can be set in the `TimeSeriesChart`. Thanks!

Comment: I just changed the one that's part of the library. Note that it may get changed back when you fetch new packages, so you might want to branch the package, or just remember to change it again if it revert to 5 minute intervals.

Comment: can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60519206/line-chart-flutter