# charts_flutter - How to set the interval on x axis ticks

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm plotting a few live time series line charts using the following snippet:

```
  new SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
    child: new charts.TimeSeriesChart([
      new charts.Series<HistoryData, DateTime>(
          id: 'test',
          colorFn: (_, __) => colourArray[dataArrayName],
          data: dataArray,
          domainFn: (HistoryData sales, _) => sales.date,
          measureFn: (HistoryData sales, _) => sales.historyValue)
    ],
        animate: true,
        dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory()),
  )

class HistoryData {
  final DateTime date;
  final double historyValue;

  HistoryData(this.date, this.historyValue);
}
```

The data displays fine but I've noticed that there is only one x axis labels:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to make it so there are many evenly spaced ticks on the x axis.

Thanks

EDIT: `dataArray` is a variable of type `List<HistoryData>`

This is the print:

`I/flutter (19864): [Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryData', Instance of 'HistoryDat...`

There are 60 `HistoryData` objects in this `List` and each `date` value in each `HistoryData` is 2 seconds apart from each other.

Comment: Print/Post the contents of your `dataArray` variable

Comment: Check my edit. Does this provide enough information?

Comment: Hm, no - can you possibly show the values of each `HistoryData` entry?

Comment: My chart follows this example: https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/simple but instead each `HistoryData` has a double value instead of int and the DateTime object is made for each instance using: `DateTime.parse('2018-10-19T15.51')` with 2 second difference between each `HistoryData` `date` value

Comment: Is it possible that each `HistoryData` has the same `DateTime` value and the charts plugin then only displays it once?

Comment: I ran a loop to print out the two properties of each `HistoryData` object. See here: https://pastebin.com/4WDsdGDn 

I'm nearly 100% sure that each `HistoryData` has a different `DateTime` value

Comment: The smallest x-axis interval is 5 minutes (but can be changed to 1 minute) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964513/format-time-labels-in-charts-flutter-time-series-chart-to-include-hhmmss/51977024#51977024)

Answer (score 11):

```
charts.TimeSeriesChart(
    _createSampleData(),
    animate: true,
    domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
      tickProviderSpec: charts.DayTickProviderSpec(increments: [1]),
      tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
        day: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
            format: 'EEE', transitionFormat: 'EEE', noonFormat: 'EEE'),
      ),
      showAxisLine: false,
    ),
  ),
```

this line sets how much inrement you want to show ticks on domain or bottom axis

```
tickProviderSpec: charts.DayTickProviderSpec(increments: [1]),
```

change increments to 2 and 3 and check the output

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for months... Thank you so much... Dostar..!!!