# Flutter Chart label text overlapping

Tags: flutter, bar-chart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

Working on Flutter Chart, the domainFn lists the days in a month, 1...31, but they are overlapping, I would like to set the label in a scale of 5 i.e 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30.

```
List<charts.Series<EventChart, String>> _createChart(
    List<EventChart> eventChart) {
        return [
            charts.Series<EventChart, String>(
                id: widget.activity,
                domainFn: (EventChart eventChart, _) => eventChart.label,
                measureFn: (EventChart eventChart, _) => eventChart.count,
                data: eventChart,
                measureUpperBoundFn: (EventChart eventChart, _) =>
                eventChart.count < 4 ? eventChart.count + 4 : eventChart.count,
                measureLowerBoundFn: (EventChart eventChart, _) => 0,
                fillColorFn: (EventChart eventChart, _) {
                  return charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault;
                },
            )
        ];
    }
);
```

BARCHART WIDGET:

```
Flexible(
    child: charts.BarChart(
        _createChart(pro.eventChart(widget.activity)
    ),
    animate: true,
    behaviors: [
        charts.LinePointHighlighter(
            drawFollowLinesAcrossChart: true,
            showHorizontalFollowLine:
            charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.all
        )
    ],
),
```

[image: screenshot of the chart]

Comment: Could you please update your post and share your code of what you have so far. It would help us determine where the problem is.

Comment: @AleksanderTG added

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885370/charts-flutter-how-to-set-the-interval-on-x-axis-ticks

Answer (score 0):

You can select the ticks to be displayed by providing a `tickProviderSpec` in the `domainAxis`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
          tickProviderSpec: charts.StaticOrdinalTickProviderSpec(
            [
              charts.TickSpec('10'),
              charts.TickSpec('15'),
              charts.TickSpec('20'),
              ...
            ]
      )),
    );
  }
```