# How do I only display hours and minutes in my Flutter Chart?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a flutter chart that shows temperature over time. Currently, the X axis shows the month and day, which I do not want. I would like it to show hours and minutes in a HH:MM format. Here is how my chart looks now:
[image: Current chart (with long date at bottom)]

Here is my chart widget code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';

final db = Firestore.instance;

class TemperatureData {
  // Requires Firestore epoch time to be converted to DateTime with  DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time * 1000)
  final int temperature;
  final DateTime time;

  TemperatureData(this.temperature, this.time);
}

List<Series> _createChartData(List<TemperatureData> temperatureData) {
  var data = [
    new Series<TemperatureData, DateTime>(
      id: 'Temperature',
      domainFn: (TemperatureData temperatureData, _) => temperatureData.time,
      measureFn: (TemperatureData temperatureData, _) =>
          temperatureData.temperature,
      data: temperatureData,
    ),
  ];

  return data;
}

List<TemperatureData> _parseTemperatureData(rawTemperatureData) {
  List<TemperatureData> parsedList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rawTemperatureData['Temperature'].length; i++) {
    parsedList.add(TemperatureData(
        rawTemperatureData['Temperature'][i]['Temperature'],
        rawTemperatureData['Temperature'][i]['Time'].toDate()));
  }
  return parsedList;
}

class TemperatureChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TemperatureChartState();
  }
}

class _TemperatureChartState extends State<TemperatureChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('SensorData')
            .document('MapTest')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              height: 300,
              child: TimeSeriesChart(
                _createChartData(_parseTemperatureData(snapshot.data)),
                animate: true,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

And here is the data I am pulling in from Firestore:
[image: Firestore screenshot]

Comment: Use a `DateTimeAxisSpec` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136832/format-time-labels-in-charts-flutter-time-series-chart/51138909#51138909

Comment: Obviously, change `dd` to some variant of `HH` or `mm` as required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can format the datetime

```
 List<TemperatureData> _parseTemperatureData(rawTemperatureData) {
  List<TemperatureData> parsedList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rawTemperatureData['Temperature'].length; i++) {
    parsedList.add(TemperatureData(
        rawTemperatureData['Temperature'][i]['Temperature'],
        DateTime.Hm().format(rawTemperatureData['Temperature'][i]['Time']).toDate()));
  }
  return parsedList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DateFormat.Hm().format() seems to return a string when a DateTime is needed for the Flutter Chart. Can DateFormat send out a DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include

```
intl: ^0.15.8
```

in your `pubspec.yaml`
if you want you can get it from https://pub.dev/packages/intl latest version
then:

```
List<TemperatureData> _parseTemperatureData(rawTemperatureData) {
  List<TemperatureData> parsedList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rawTemperatureData['Temperature'].length; i++) {
    parsedList.add(TemperatureData(
        rawTemperatureData['Temperature'][i]['Temperature'],
        DateTime.Hm().format(rawTemperatureData['Temperature'][i]['Time'])));
  }
  return parsedList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DateFormat.Hm().format() seems to return a string when a DateTime is needed for the Flutter Chart. Can DateFormat send out a DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your domainAxis:

```
tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
        hour: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
          format: 'H:mm',
          transitionFormat: 'H:mm',
        ),
      ),
```