# Flutter charts tickProviderSpec to 15 minutes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm creating my flutter chart, it contains the last 3 hours of data from each minute.
I want to show a tick every 15 minutes. My data keeps updating all the time from an API, so its dynamic.

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return charts.TimeSeriesChart(
  seriesList,
  animate: animate,
  dateTimeFactory: charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
  domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
    tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
      hour: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
        format: 'H:mm',
        transitionFormat: 'H:mm',
        noonFormat: 'H:mm',
      ),
    ),
    //tickProviderSpec: HOW CAN I SET THIS TO 15MIN?,
  ),
  behaviors: [
    charts.SlidingViewport(),
    charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
  ],
  defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(
    includePoints: false,
    strokeWidthPx: 3,
  ),
);
}
```

I tried different solutions, for example from: [Change X-axis Line Chart flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531804/change-x-axis-line-chart-flutter)

However this is based on static data, which I don't have. 
Is there a solution to show a tick every 15minutes?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? The algorithm governing DateTime ticks is incredibly stupid.

Comment: @zerox1212 sadly not... still looking for a solution.

Comment: @zerox1212 I moved from flutter chart to syncfusion, that fixed my problem.

Comment: Is the syncfusion chart good for time series data? Was the migration hard... I'm revisiting this as well..

Comment: @zerox1212 yes it is, Im also using it. Needed some time to refactor the data structure, but its doable.