# Load pdf file from url

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

I have this url from server
https://xxxx.pdf20200529". How can I load it as pdf in my flutter app?

I use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file), but nothing happened.

**Code**

```
OpenFile.open(value);  // value is https://xxxx.pdf20200529
```

**Edit**

```
 generatePDF(dynamic value) async {
    final filename = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(value));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    OpenFile.open(file.path);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening PDF's in Flutter is pretty fiddly. So I suggest you use a package. flutter_full_pdf_viewer works pretty well and is easy to use, but there are others out there.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer

This will be your PDF Screen:

```
class PDFScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String pathPDF = "";
  PDFScreen(this.pathPDF);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PDFViewerScaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Document"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        path: pathPDF);
  }
}
```

Navigate to it like this. Make sure to pass the local path to the screen.:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PDFScreen(pathPDF)),
```

Comment: can url opened as pdf?

Comment: @Tony I don't believe so, but I could be wrong. PDF's are pretty large, so downloading them and saving them locally for the user is usually a pretty good idea. The "Example" section in that link has a good example of how to use it.

Comment: @Tony look at point 4 on the link i sent. It walks you through how to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214921/discussion-between-benedikt-j-schlegel-and-tony).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [url_launcher 5.4.10](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

As far as I know it opens pdfs as well.

Comment: I don't want open through browser

Answer (score 0):

I miss `.pdf` in this line

```
File file = new File('$dir/$filename.pdf');
```

After add `.pdf`, all PDF viewer able to open.

Comment: can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136832/format-time-labels-in-charts-flutter-time-series-chart